# HTML not downloaded correctly

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I've been trying to download the source code of the Google News rss feed. It's downloaded correctly except from links that are shown weirdly.

```
static String urlNotizie = "https://news.google.it/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=it&hl=it&output=rss";
Document docHtml = Jsoup.connect(urlNotizie).get();
String html = docHtml.toString();
System.out.println(html);
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
    <generator>
     NFE/1.0
    </generator>
    <title>Prima pagina - Google News</title>
    <link />http://news.google.it/news?pz=1&amp;ned=it&amp;hl=it
    <language>
     it
    </language>
    <webmaster>
     news-feedback@google.com
    </webmaster>
    <copyright>
     &amp;copy;2013 Google
    </copyright> [...]
```

Using a URLConnection I'm able to output the correct source of the page. But during parse I have the same issue as above, where it spits a list of `<link />.` (Again only with links. Parsing other things works fine). URLConnection example:

```
        URL u = new URL(urlNotizie);
        URLConnection yc = u.openConnection();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                yc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
        String html = builder.toString();
        System.out.println("HTML " + html);

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements listaTitoli = doc.select("title");
        Elements listaCategorie = doc.select("category");
        Elements listaDescrizioni = doc.select("description");
        Elements listaUrl = doc.select("link");
        System.out.println(listaUrl);
```

Comment: Its downloaded correctly or else jsoup wouldn't be able to turn it into a Document, things apparently go wrong in the toString() method. You could always just use an URLConnection or Apache HttpClient to fetch the RSS data directly of course.

Comment: Updated question with new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is designed as a [HTML parser](http://jsoup.org), not as a XML (nor RSS) parser.

The HTML [`<link>` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) is specified as not having any body. It would be [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) to have a `<link>` element with a body like as in your XML.

You can parse XML using Jsoup, but you need to explicitly [tell](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#parser%28org.jsoup.parser.Parser%29) it to switch to [XML parsing mode](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#xmlParser%28%29).

Replace

```
Document docHtml = Jsoup.connect(urlNotizie).get();
```

by

```
Document docXml = Jsoup.connect(urlNotizie).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();
```

Comment: I did: `Document docHtml = Jsoup.connect(urlNotizie).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();
String html = docHtml.toString();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);` but it still doesn't work. It keeps parsing weird links.

Comment: Huh? Why exactly are you doing `String html = docHtml.toString(); Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);`? Get rid of those lines. You're here simply re-parsing the parsed XML as HTML which makes no utter sense, as explained in my answer. Just use `docXml.select("link")` and so on.